# SQL where var in list statement using like

Tags: sql

I am struggling trying to find a solution to the following problem:

Assume that I have a DB-table, `TABLE` like this (it actually has 800 000 rows)

```
 Avtal AvtalsOmråde  Fordon
0    E32        Ekerö  156950
1    E32        Ekerö  156951
2    E32        Ekerö  156952
3    E32        Ekerö  156953
4    E32        Ekerö  156954
5    E32        Ekerö  156955
6    E32        Ekerö  156956
7    E32        Ekerö  156957
8    E32        Ekerö  156958
9    E32        Ekerö  156959
10   E32        Ekerö  156960
11   E32        Ekerö  156961
12   E32        Ekerö  156962
13   E32        Ekerö  156963
14   E32        Ekerö  156964
15   E32        Ekerö  156965
16   E32        Ekerö  156966
17   E32        Ekerö  157001
18   E32        Ekerö  157002
19   E32        Ekerö  157003
20   E32        Ekerö  157004
21   E32        Ekerö  157005
22   E32        Ekerö  157006
23   E32        Ekerö  157185
24   E32        Ekerö  157200
25   E32        Ekerö  157201
26   E32        Ekerö  157202
27   E32        Ekerö  157203
28   E32        Ekerö  157204
29   E32        Ekerö  157205
30   E32        Ekerö  157206
31   E32        Ekerö  157222
32   E32        Ekerö  157223
33   E32        Ekerö  157224
34   E32        Ekerö  157225
35   E32        Ekerö  157226
36   E32        Ekerö  157300
37   E32        Ekerö  157301
38   E32        Ekerö  157302
39   E32        Ekerö  157500
40   E32        Ekerö  157571
```

Assume that I want to find a specific `Fordon`, say 157300, but I only know the last part of that identifier (7300). Then

```
Select * 
from TABLE as T
where T.Fordon like '%7300%'
```

does the trick and returns

```
36   E32        Ekerö  157300
```

Now, suppose that I have a list of 200 parts of `Fordon`-identifiers `(7300, 3435, 0032,.....)` (there are always the last 4 digits of a `Fordon`-identifier). I cannot find a way to do exactly the same thing. I know I need to use `OR` to do so but i have no clue to how to do so.

An alternative would be to return all the rows for which the variable `Fordon` has the last four digits like the four digits of the list.

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another way is to do so, get the last 4 digit of your Fordon number and try to match it with  the list you have :

```
Select * 
from TABLE as T
where RIGHT(T.Fordon,4) in (7300, 3435, 0032,.....)
```

Answer (score 1):

If Fordon is an integer (or some other numeric type), why don't you try some math? If it's the last four digits, then you should be able to calculate modulo 10,000. In your case:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE AS T WHERE T.Fordon%10000 IN (7300, 3435, 0032, .....);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `substring` and `in`:

```
select * 
from TABLE as T
where substring(T.Fordon, 3, 4) in ('7300', '3435', '0032')
```